# How to select an existing form when adding a WFFM Form using Experience Editor

Tags: wffm

When we add a new Form rendering to a placeholder the only options that are available on the wizard are to **Create a blank form** or **Select a form to copy**:

[image: WFFM Form Wizard]

There is no option to use existing forms that may have been previously created and used on other pages.

Does the WFFM module support choosing an existing form option while creating or adding a forms in a placeholder? How can we enable the option to allow selection of existing forms, or how can our content editors re-use the forms from other areas of the site?

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 update 3 version.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to select an existing form when you add a form onto a page in Sitecore 8.0 update 3 or earlier versions.

One option is to upgrade your Sitecore instance to 8.0 Update 6, in which this option was added, but be aware that there were a number of other big changes in this release including a number of code changes and updates to the front-end framework to use Bootstrap which may require you to spend a significant time updating your styling to fix this.

An alternative is to override the Form Selector and provide your own implementation to add a "Use existing form" option. [I have previously written a blog post](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/webforms-for-marketers-allow-selection-of-existing-forms/) on this exact thing for Sitecore 8.0 Update-3

### Steps to override the Form Selector

Make a copy of **/sitecore/shell/Applications/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/InsertFormWizard.xml** and copy it to **/sitecore/shell/Override** folder.

Update the file to change the `Codebeside` tag to point to your implementation:

```
<WizardForm Application="Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Insert Form Wizard" CodeBeside="MyProject.Custom.WFFM.UI.InsertFormWizard, MyProject.Custom">
```

Add a new RadioButton that will allow selection for existing forms:

```
<Border Margin="10px">
  <Radiobutton ID="ChooseExistingForm" Name="ChooseOperation" Value="existing"/>
</Border>
```

And create a Class that for the code behind. You want to check if the new "Existing Form" option has been selected and if so vary the wizard page shown appropriately:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Custom.WFFM.UI
{
    public class InsertFormWizard : Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.InsertFormWizard
    {
        protected Radiobutton ChooseExistingForm;

        protected override bool ActivePageChanging(string page, ref string newpage)
        {
            if (newpage == "SelectPlaceholder" && page == "SelectForm" && this.ChooseExistingForm.Checked)
                newpage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Placeholder) ? "SelectPlaceholder" : "ConfirmationPage";

            if (this.ChooseExistingForm.Checked && newpage == "AnalyticsPage")
                newpage = "ConfirmationPage";

            return base.ActivePageChanging(page, ref newpage);
        }

        protected override void OnNext(object sender, EventArgs formEventArgs)
        {
            if (this.NextButton.Header == "Confirm" && this.ChooseExistingForm.Checked)
            {
                this.SaveExistingFormSelection();
                SheerResponse.SetModified(false);
                this.Next();
                return;
            }
            base.OnNext(sender, formEventArgs);
        }

        private void SaveExistingFormSelection()
        {
            Item source = ExistingFormSelection();
            this.ServerProperties[this.newFormUri] = source.Uri.ToString();
            Registry.SetString("/Current_User/Dialogs//sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Forms.FormDesigner", "1250,500");
            SheerResponse.SetDialogValue(source.ID.ToString());
        }

        private Item ExistingFormSelection()
        {
            string queryString = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetQueryString("la");
            Language result = Context.ContentLanguage;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
                Language.TryParse(Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetQueryString("la"), out result);

            Item source = this.FormsRoot.Database.GetItem(this.multiTree.Selected, result);
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the minimum code required to make this work. I suggest reading the blog post for a more thorough explanation and the full code is also available in [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/92377635a06ac86d627a).

The user will now have the option to select an existing form using the wizard.

[image: WFFM Existing Form Selector]

Comment: can you explain the details of code where I need to put and how i call this code from my project.  you just copy and paste the code from google!

Comment: Considering I wrote the original article, I wouldn't exactly call that copy+pasting from Google. I already told you what you do, what exactly in the `Steps to override the Form Selector` section is not clear?

Comment: @Agent47, this is not a support site meant to do your homework for you. If there is a specific thing in the answer you do not understand, ask to get it clarified. Being rude to the contributing members of this site is not going to get you any help any faster. Quite the opposite.

Comment: Sorry for your misunderstanding.I didn't understand where I exactly call for this code.

Comment: There is nothing to call, from the linked [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/92377635a06ac86d627a), add the Class to your project and copy the XML file to `/sitecore/shell/Override` folder, editing [Line 35](https://gist.github.com/jammykam/92377635a06ac86d627a#file-insertformwizard-xml-L35) to match your class name. There is nothing else to change, Sitecore will pick up the changed Form wizard from the Override folder. I'm not sure I can spoon feed you the answer any more than that.